# JFolder::create: Could not create directory Warning: Failed to move file! (Joomla + Windows Azure)

Tags: azure, joomla2.5

I installed Joomla on a website on Windows Azure. After trying to update the Joomla version or uploading a new template I get the following error

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Warning: Failed to move file!
```

For me it's clear that the problem is regarding permissions, so the question is, how can it be solved?

Since the Azure architecture (basically the replication) makes you difficult to just change the permissions of the folders, and it is not possible to modify the folder permissions on a Windows server using FTP, I feel like I'm on a dead end.

Comment: Do you have the FTP layer enabled?

Comment: Bummer. You are likely out of luck then since it is a cloud service and the likely changes that will need to be made are server level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should definitely be possible. When installing a component JFolder::create is called several times.

I think that you are passing a wrong path or something to the actual call. Have you tried a simple test using the native mkdir()?